# Unable to sign in my GitHub account in GitHub Desktop and Vs Code

Tags: github

Whenever I am trying to sign in in GitHub Desktop or Vs Code, it just keeps loading and does not even redirect to browser.

I restart everything. But it did nothing. I even switch browser, check the firewall and proxy, off my antivirus, but yet nothing happens.

Comment: Hi, verify that your system's date and time settings are correct. Also clearing cache and cookies in the browser might also help resolve the issue.